# Java SQL Exception: Error when parsing callable statement <missing parameter type>

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to call a MySQL stored procedure from within a Java application. However I receive the following error: `java.sql.SQLException: Internal error when parsing callable statement metadata (missing parameter type)`.

The stored procedure functions correctly when called from outside the application. Also, the application does successfully connect to the database.

- MySQL Server: 5.5.27
- java version "1.7.0_15"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Java Code:

```
protected Connection mysql;
...
try {
    CallableStatement query = this.mysql.prepareCall("{call spInsertUser(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
    query.setString(1, "user");
    query.setString(2, "password");
    query.setString(3, "test");
    query.setString(4, "test");
    query.setString(5, "test");
    query.setString(6, "test");
    query.setString(7, "test");
    query.execute();
    query.close();
    this.mysql.close();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

MySQL store procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spInsertUser`(IN `nick` varchar(30),IN `pass` varchar(255),IN `param1` varchar(255),IN `param2`varchar(255),IN `param3` varchar(22), IN `param4` varchar(255), IN `param5` varchar(255))
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  DECLARE uid INT DEFAULT 0;

  # check if nick exists
  DECLARE userExists INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT count(*) INTO userExists FROM users WHERE nick = nick;
  IF (userExists > 0) THEN
    # do nothing if nick already exists
    # SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'User already exists!';
  ELSE
    # if nick doesn't exist, insert it
    INSERT INTO users (nick, pass, param1, created, active, param2) VALUES (nick, pass, param1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0, param2);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO uid;

    IF (uid IS NOT NULL AND uid > 0) THEN
      # create email
      INSERT INTO emails (uid, email) VALUES (uid, email);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Internal error when parsing callable statement metadata (missing parameter type)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getCallStmtParameterTypes(DatabaseMetaData.java:1836)
at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureOrFunctionColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:4305)
at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:4146)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.determineParameterTypes(CallableStatement.java:856)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:629)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CallableStatement.<init>(JDBC4CallableStatement.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.getInstance(CallableStatement.java:523)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.parseCallableStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4313)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:4397)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:4371)
at pack.File.method(File.java:65)
```

Comment: code all working fine... did u try any other Stored procedure other than this from Java.? I wana check whether it s problem with Mysql Java communication..

Comment: Please share the Complete Stored Procedure. I wana check in my enev.

Comment: I receive the same error using other (complete) stored procedures. And I'm using the same credentials for procedure creation as within my tests and the application. 

I've added a snippet of the stored procedure used in this example.

Comment: then it should be the Problem with Mysql env. No stored procedure gives the complete Result.

Comment: Thank Akshay but, I'm not sure that I follow. This particular stored procedure doesn't return a Result nor does the application expect one. Do all `CallableStatement`'s expect data to be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's certainly not the most ideal solution, I `DROP`'d then redefined the (same) stored procedure to circumvent this error. It seems the meta data was some how corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that when the parameter is defined with no blank space between name and type, it raises the error

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spInsertUser`(IN `nick` varchar(30),IN `pass` varchar(255),IN `param1` varchar(255),IN `param2`varchar(255),IN `param3` varchar(22), IN `param4` varchar(255), IN `param5` varchar(255))
```

`param2`varchar(255) must be `param2` varchar(255)

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your sql codes,check about the blank space.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `verifyregister`(IN `cdkey` varchar(16), IN `ingsid` int, IN `inusername` varchar(128) character set utf8, OUT `retcode` int)
```