# java.sql.SQLException: Internal error when parsing callable statement metadata (missing parameter type)

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

For nearly 2 hours now I'm looking for a solution, but can't find one ...

I'm getting this error and I can't find where it comes from, it's driving me crazy. Can you guys help me ?

The error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Internal error when parsing callable statement
>   metadata (missing parameter type)

And the part of the code where it comes from :

```
public char checkMap(int x, int y) {
        char c = ' ';

        try {
            DAOConnection co = new DAOConnection(DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection());

            final String sql = "{call Selectlvl1(?,?)}";
            final CallableStatement call = co.getConnection().prepareCall("{call Selectlvl1(?,?)}"); 
            call.setInt(x, x);
            call.setInt(y, y);
            call.execute();
            final ResultSet resultSet = call.getResultSet();
            c = resultSet.getString("symbol").charAt(0);

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            // Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return c;

    }
```

EDIT : Just so you know, I've been driving some tests, and the line the error ca
me up with is the "CallableStatement" one.

EDIT 2 : The SQL Procedure :

> CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Selectlvl1`(IN `p_x`
>   INT(3), IN `p_y` INT(3))  SELECT symbol FROM LorannProject.level1
>   where `x` = p_x && `y` = p_y;

The Stack Trace ( part of it ) :

> java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:790)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5240)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5163)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5202)
>     at model.DAOConnection.checkMap(DAOConnection.java:24)  at
>   model.Model.getMap1(Model.java:41)

Note that now, after changing the call.setInt(), the error is now "Illegaloperation on empty result set.".

EDIT 3 : Just adding some news, I now have another error :

java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

I think ( pretty sure ) it comes from this line :

```
    c = resultSet.getString("symbol").charAt(0);
```

I am trying to take the first char from the only column called "symbol", I do not know if this line is right.

Comment: You probably meant : `call.setInt(1, x);` and `call.setInt(2, y);`. You have to provide the right index for each placeholder of your statement.

Comment: Please post the stack trace as well as the signature of the stored procedure.

Comment: Just added it.

@Berger : It changes the error code but it does not work yet. Thank you mate !

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15601637/5743988)?

Comment: Yep, did it, didn't resolve the case.

Comment: Now, the problem is you are not advancing the resultset cursor. You need to do a `resultSet.next()` before `resultSet.getString()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    c = resultSet.getString("symbol").charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Did it, now it shows some sprites, but not all of them. I still have the same error though, it is dealing with empty results. How can I say something like "if(resultSet.next() is empty){ c = '-'} ?

Comment: @Prototype When you initialize char c , just set it to '-' instead of a space. That way, if you don't go in the if statement, then c is '-'

Comment: you could also simple add an `else` block